# Find optimal chunk size using opt_chunk_size() in lidR catalog?

Tags: lidar, las, optimization, lidr, catalog

Is there a way to find the optimal chunk size using `opt_chunk_size()` when using a lidR catalog?

I seem to always randomly choose integer values until the program quits throwing errors at me. For example, this is from the `catalog_apply()` [lidR documentation (p.11)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf):

```r
## ===================================================
## Example 2: compute a rumple index on surface points
## ===================================================
rumple_index_surface = function(cluster, res)
{
las = readLAS(cluster)
if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
las <- lasfiltersurfacepoints(las, 1)
rumple <- grid_metrics(las, ~rumple_index(X,Y,Z), res)
bbox <- raster::extent(cluster)
rumple <- raster::crop(rumple, bbox)
return(rumple)
}
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
project <- readLAScatalog(LASfile)
opt_chunk_buffer(project) <- 1
opt_chunk_size(project) <- 120 # small because this is a dummy example.
opt_select(project) <- "xyz" # read only the coordinates.
opt <- list(raster_alignment = 20) # catalog_apply will adjust the chunks if required
output <- catalog_apply(project, rumple_index_surface, res = 20, .options = opt)
output <- do.call(raster::merge, output)
plot(output, col = height.colors(50))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control of the chunk size intends mainly to enable the processing of big files on computers with a small configuration. You don't have a lot of RAM but you need to process high density file? You can process quarters of the files.

The default is 0 meaning that you process by file. I rarely change that myself except in the documentation for the need of the examples. You are not expecting to encounter trouble with other values except maybe for very small and irrelevant ones (e.g chunks of 20 m in `grid_metrics` with a resolution of 20 m).

However there is one case where it can matters: exponentially complex methods. For example the `li2012` method is quadratically complex with the number of points meaning you will process faster 4 quarters of a file than the whole file.

Comment: Is there any way to quantitatively determine which size to use in complex methods? For example `Total_Size/4`? Also, is there any way to know which methods are complex and require chunks?

Comment: No. This definitively not trivial. And there is no way to know the complex methods because it is not necessarily obvious even for me. I'd say that `li2012()` is computed in 0(n²) or more. TIN-based methods are computed in `0(n log n)` according to the state of the art. Other methods are computed in `0(n)` or something not too bad. `li2012()` has been added a long time ago but now I would not have added it because of its complexity that makes it hardly computable on broad coverage.

Comment: In `lidRplugins` you will find more "problematic" algorithms not added in `lidR` because of the computation time. And yet I'm sure I could linearize `li2012` one day or another.